# Facebook using content behind proxy

Tags: php, wordpress, iis, proxy

I've set up an Asp.Net website as `https://mywebsite.com`. I've also got a subdomained blog, `http://blog.mywebsite.com` which resolves to `https://mywebsite.com/blog` through a reverse proxy.

The reverse proxy has been set up using Application Request Routing and the blog is hosted on a different server using Wordpress.

All is well except for Facebook, which insists on posting my content under the blog subdomain, even when I'm using my alias. I've also made changes to WP-config, so that all urls are rendered as `https://mywebsite.com/blog`.

I've Googled this to death, but the space is filled with other crud about circumventing banned accounts etc.

Anyone have any ideas as to how I can work around this and get my posts posted under the url I enter? I'm manually posting.

Thanks in advance.